# Create a function which accepts an array and a defined length 6 and outputs array of length 2

Tags: php, arrays

Definition:  **Create a function which accepts an array and a defined length L and outputs array of length L**

a) Input array properties:

1. It will have a fixed input maximum length ( N )
2. It will have few elements filled (up to length L )

The function should modify the array so that the remaining places of input array should be filled in with the already filled one in the same order.
the function should output the modified array

For ex-

1) input array: `[1,2]` and Length: (L=6) (Total len:6, length of elements):

Output array should be `[1,2,1,2,1,2]`

2) Another example (for Length L=6)-input array: `[1,2,3,4]`

Output array: `[1,2,3,4,1,2]`

3) `[1,2,3]` (for Length L=5)

Output array: `[1,2,3,1,2]`

**My code**

```
<?php ///sdsd
$arr1 = array(1, 2);
$length1 = 6;
function one($arr1, $length1)
{
    for ($i = 1;$i < $length;$i++)
    {
    }
    //Output array should be [1,2,1,2,1,2]
}
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$length2 = 6;
function two($arr2, $length2)
{
    for ($i = 1;$i < $length;$i++)
    {
    }
    //Output array should be [1,2,3,4,1,2]
}
?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow do not provide solutions for assignments

Comment: @sumit is correct, Stack Overflow is not a place to let people write code for you, we are here to help with specific problems which couldn't be solved by the person who asked the question. If you want to let someone code for you you should look for other ideas or - which you normally should do - solve the task yourself (It is not that difficult btw.).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 6];

function arrayRepeat(&$array, $length)
{
    if($length <= count($array)) {
        $array = array_slice($array, 0, $length);
    } else {
        $addLength = $length - count($array);

        for($i = 0; $i < $addLength; $i++) {
            $array[] = $array[$i];
        }
    }
}

arrayRepeat($arr, 6);
```